# unable to attach file to an ACTION_SEND intent

Tags: android, email, android-intent, attachment

I'm trying to attach a text file to an email and I'm getting a weird error that I hope someone can help me with. It works fine when the user selects the gmail app from the chooser, but if they select the built in mail application, they see a toast that says "Unable to attach file".

The code looks like this:

```
public static void sendMail(Context context, String emailBody, String emailSubject, String emailAddress, String attachmentFilename){
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.setType("plain/text");

    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { emailAddress});
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, emailSubject);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, emailBody);

    if(attachmentFilename != null) {
        //Add the attachment by specifying a reference to our custom ContentProvider and the specific file of interest
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("content://" + Settings.VYPR_LOG_PROVIDER_AUTHORITY + "/" + attachmentFilename));
    }
    context.startActivity(emailIntent);
}
```

Anyone have any thoughts on what might be going on here? Most of what I have seen on here has to do with the attachment being on the SD card. I actually didn't write this code myself, but it seems like that must not be the issue here since it *does* work if the user selects the gmail app rather than the built in one.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experienced the same problem long time ago. Had to make the use of the Gmail app mandatory to send attachments. I could not figure out why the built-in email app did not work.

If you are trying to receive the attachment to a specific email address, you may also consider deploying a web service to upload the attachment.

Hope it helps.

Comment: It just seems to be related to the ContentProvider approach not being compatible with a lot of the ACTION_SEND handlers. If you want to use it, your best bet is to probably make the gmail app mandatory. Otherwise you'll need to save the file to external storage